# Android studio connection error

Tags: java, android

I am using *Android Studio 2.3* and getting this error

[image]

P.S. I updated it to 3.0 and got the same error but this error didn't come on 2.3.3 but I want to use 2.3 because 2.3.3 gives me some errors. Also, I have a working internet connection with my pc.
I also tried other Question regarding this question but sadly didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a HTTPS connection issue.

Try changing the Project's **build.gradle** file as follows:

```
repositories {
   //google()
   //jcenter()
   maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com" }
}
```

These changes are to be done on 2 places. Hope it works after this.